# Smooth edge loops on sphere

Tags: modeling, mesh, topology

I'm trying to model indented circles onto a sphere with clean topology. I think I have accomplished that, but I am struggling to maintain the smoothness of the sphere with the added edge loops. I can't remove these added ridges. I've tried to increase subsurf, subdivide, and manually add in edgeloops to even out the topology density, but this just exaggerated the effect. How can I maintain a smooth spherical look while still having a clean topology for these indents? I created the sphere by subdividing a cube several times, and then applying a subsurf.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try to avoid those extra edge loops. If your sphere has not enough vertices to allow you to create your holes then recreate a new sphere with more vertices, but it looks like you have enough. Also, before the hole extrusion, you can use a *Shrinkwrap* modifier with a second sphere as *Object* to make sure that the whole shape is still a sphere.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a job for the *Cast modifier*.

Add it to the end of your modifier stack, and set *factor* to 1.

[image]